# Get value from hidden field

Tags: jquery, input, hidden

Why is this not working correct when i give the input field type=hidden? When the input field is nog hidden the alert give me the ID-code I want.

```
<input id="scanID" name="scanID" type="hidden">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scanID").keypress(function(e){
     //key code 13 is "enter",  
        if(e.keyCode==13){   
                //print out the barcode
            alert($("#scanID").val());
                     //clear the input field for next scan
             $("#scanID").val('');
                    //kill the "enter" event
             return false;
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no values assigned to the hidden input. Hence it is not showing any value. Where are you assigning the value to it?

Comment: With scanner I scan the ID and have tried this:   if(e.keyCode==13){   
   //print out the barcode
   var test = $('#scanID').val();
                        alert (test);

nothing happans

Comment: Your element is hidden and hence it would never have a keypress would never occur on it.

Comment: Ok I understand that, but is there an solution for?

Answer (score 2):

That's because a hidden element cannot gain focus, therefore the keypress event will never occur on it. You should be using a different input type.

An alternative solution would be to use a normal input, and `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` it with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

you can add keypress event to the document if you want :

```
<input id="scanID" name="scanID" type="hidden" value="yourValue">

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(this).keypress(function(e){
         //key code 13 is "enter",  
            if(e.keyCode==13){   
                    //print out the barcode
                alert($("#scanID").val());
                         //clear the input field for next scan
                 $("#scanID").val('');
                        //kill the "enter" event
                 return false;
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: But then whenever he presses enter no matter where it'll trigger it.

Comment: this solution gives me an alert but no value

Comment: @dymo <input id="scanID" name="scanID" type="hidden" value="yourValue">